# How to link adwords account through only one time Authentication using outh2?

Tags: google-ads-api

I am having trouble to get report using Outh2 Authentication flow using PHP for the AdWords API & need some help. Here is the situation:

I have a client on AdWords that I want to pull reports for through the AdWords API (we have a developer token , Refresh Token for this). Let's say that, in AdWords page, Login prompt open every time for login. I would like to implement report using only one time Outh2 login and like show as third party report :

Below is the following code that I try to get working for one time login :

```
$oauth2 = new OAuth2([
    'authorizationUri' => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth',
    'tokenCredentialUri' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
    'redirectUri' => 'http://XXXXXXXX/XXXXX',
    'clientId' => '1XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX',
    'clientSecret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'scope' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords',
    'refresh_token'=>'4/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'username' => 'XXXXX.XXXXXXX.XX@gmail.com',
    'password'=>'XXXXXXXXX']);


  if (!isset($_GET['code']))
   {
    $oauth2->setState(sha1(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(1024)));
    $_SESSION['oauth2state'] = $oauth2->getState();
    $config = ['access_type' => 'offline'];
    header('Location: ' . $oauth2->buildFullAuthorizationUri($config));
    exit;
  } else if (empty($_GET['state']) || ($_GET['state'] !== $_SESSION['oauth2state']))
  {
   unset($_SESSION['oauth2state']);
   exit('Invalid state.');
 }else
 {
   $oauth2->setCode($_GET['code']);
   $authToken = $oauth2->fetchAuthToken();
   $session = (new AdWordsSessionBuilder())
   ->fromFile()
   ->withOAuth2Credential($oauth2)
   ->build();
 }
```

Below is the following code using that I Generate Report :

```
$selector2 = new Selector();
$selector2->setFields(['AllConversionRate','AccountCurrencyCode','AveragePosition','Clicks','Impressions','Ctr','AverageCpc', 'Cost', 'Conversions','Query','Date']);
$reportDefinition2= new ReportDefinition(); // Create report definition.
$reportDefinition2->setSelector($selector2);
$reportDefinition2->setReportName('Criteria performance report #'.uniqid());
$reportDefinition2->setDateRangeType(ReportDefinitionDateRangeType::LAST_7_DAYS);
$reportDefinition2->setReportType(ReportDefinitionReportType::SEARCH_QUERY_PERFORMANCE_REPORT); // report type
$reportDefinition2->setDownloadFormat(DownloadFormat::CSV);
$reportDownloader2 = new ReportDownloader($session); // Download report.
$reportDownloadResult2 = $reportDownloader2->downloadReport($reportDefinition2);
$reportAsString2 = $reportDownloadResult2->getAsString();
print_r($reportAsString2);
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app was not helpful enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Adwrods Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/samples/php/reporting)

**First Of all For generate Adwords Performance repoting Offline access, You have to generate offline session by using "refress token"**

```
Please follow these steps :-

Step 1. Built Offline credentials 

public function credentialBuilder($refresstoken) {

    $refresh_token = trim($refresstoken);
    $configIniFilePath = "adsapi_php.ini"; // place adsapi_ini on root (set correct path)

    /* ------  set client credentials ---------------- */

    $oauth2_clientId = CLIENT_ID; // set Client Id 
    $oauth2_clientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET; // set client secret 
    $refresh_token = $refresh_token; // set refress token get after oauth2 verification 
    $oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())->fromFile(self::$configIniFilePath);
    $oAuth2Credential->withClientId($oauth2_clientId);
    $oAuth2Credential->withClientSecret($oauth2_clientSecret);
    $oAuth2Credential->withRefreshToken($refresh_token);
    $credential = $oAuth2Credential->build();

    return $credential; // return credentials 
    }

Step 2. Built Report setting 

private function reportSettings() {
    $reportSettings = (new ReportSettingsBuilder())
            ->fromFile(self::$configIniFilePath)
            ->includeZeroImpressions(false)
            ->build();

    return $reportSettings;
    }

Step 3. Generate Report session 

public function reportSession($credential = null, $customerId = null) {
    $reportSettings = $this->reportSettings(); // get report setting from function

    $session = (new AdWordsSessionBuilder())
            ->fromFile(self::$configIniFilePath)
            ->withOAuth2Credential($credential) // set credentials using credentialBuilder() function
            ->withClientCustomerId($customerId) // set client customer ID
            ->withReportSettings($reportSettings) 
            ->build();

    return $session;
    }

// Function for get campaign reporting 

public function campaignReporting() {

    $credential = $this->credentialBuilder();
    $session = $obj->reportSession($credential, "Sub_customer_client_id"); // set client id 

    $reportQuery = 'SELECT CampaignId,CampaignName,Impressions,Clicks,Cost,Ctr,
                    AverageCost,Conversions,CostPerConversion,ConversionRate,ViewThroughConversions,AverageCpc,AveragePosition
                    FROM CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT DURING YESTERDAY';

    // Download report as a string.
    $reportDownloader = new ReportDownloader($session);
    $reportDownloadResult = $reportDownloader->downloadReportWithAwql($reportQuery, 'CSV');
    $csvData = $reportDownloadResult->getAsString(); // generate report as string 

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($csvData);
}
```

Comment: thank for reply but use this code after getting error -> `Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Cannot have both service account flow and installed/web application flow credential values set` ...

Comment: Follow this url :- https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/samples/php/reporting

Comment: getting Fatal error: Uncaught Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201702\cm\ApiException: Details: [fieldPath: ; trigger: <null>; errorString: AuthorizationError.USER_PERMISSION_DENIED] for third party user.
i use $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);